# How to save table cell's background colour and styles of border line (OO.Org Writer)?

Tags: formatting, openoffice, openoffice-writer

**What I want**

I want to reuse table format by styles, but only table's text format is saved.

**How I try to do it**

How I save table style:

- I select cells
- styles and formatting > new style from selection

How I apply style:

- I select cells I want formatted
- style and formatting > double click on style I just saved

**Question**

How to save cell's background colour and styles of border line?

**Context**

I have Writer 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

OOo Writer has different categories of styles, so the first step is to distinguish between them. Here's an overview over the different categories (from [OOo docs](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Stylist)):

[image: styles]

Make sure you're working with **Paragraph Styles** if you want to format cells: The cell formatting depends on the Paragraph style of its content

If you've created a new style as you've described, make sure that it has the desired style definitions. You can access (and modify) them using the "`Modify...`" entry from the style's context menu (again, [OOo docs](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Modifying_styles)):

[image: modify style]

using the paragraph style's border and background settings, you can modify table cells, too. If it doesn't work for you:

1. check if the paragraph style has the proper settings;
2. reset the cell style to the paragraph style defaults using Menu "Format" -> "Default Formatting";
3. Select the cell or its text and apply the paragraph style again.

This works at least in OOo 3.2 and LibreOffice 3.5.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer doesn't work for newer versions of LibreOffice. [From the manual:](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/3/31/WG4209-WorkingWithTables.pdf)

To create your own AutoFormat, proceed as follows:

1. Create a table and manually format it as you wish, including borders, spacing of text from  the top and bottom borders, fonts to be used in the table heading and data cells, and 
   background colors.
2. Position the cursor anywhere in the table and then click 
   Table > AutoFormat
3. On the AutoFormat dialog, click Add and give the table format a name in the Add AutoFormat dialog and click OK
4. The newly named AutoFormat now appears as an available format. Click 
   OK
   to close the 
   AutoFormat dialog.

Table AutoFormats record the following table-level properties:

- Break
- Keep with next paragraph
- Repeat heading
- Allow table to split across pages
- Allow rows to break across pages
- Merge adjacent line styles
- Table shadow