# Table background not being saved when I save table style in Libre Office Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I'm trying to save a table style as a named style in LibreOffice writer. My process so far has been as follows:

Select the table whose style I want to save, then use the following

```
Format Menu ->
    Styles and Formatting ->
        Styles and Formatting Dialog ->
            New Style From Selection ->
                Enter style name and save.
```

Writer puts the new style under the `Table Contents` sub-tree within the Styles and Formatting tree view. The `Borders` property seems to be saved, but the `Background` property is not.

Per [How to save table cell's background colour and styles of border line (OO.Org Writer)?](https://superuser.com/questions/442942/how-to-save-table-cells-background-colour-and-styles-of-border-line-oo-org-wri), I made sure that I had chosen 'Paragraph Styles' before I saved the table style. I have also ensured that I'm only selecting a style from a single cell, thereby ensuring that I'm not trying to save conflicting background styles.

By right-clicking on the name of my style, I can see that there is no background color set. I can modify the background manually -- however, the background color doesn't extend all the way to the border of the cell; it only covers the text area.

So far, I've been using

LibreOffice 3.5.4.2 
Build ID: 350m1(Build:2)

Running on Ubuntu 10.04.

Technical details:

I unzipped the ODF file and opened styles.xml and content.xml.

Both files contain style information; styles.xml contains the default ODF styles, plus any named styles created by users. Content.xml contains anonymous style information tied directly to content (E.g. if you high-light text using the 'high-light' tool, this style information will be saved to content.xml). Here's the interesting thing:

This is from styles.xml:

```
<style:style 
      style:name="new_20_table_20_heading" 
      style:display-name="new table heading" 
      style:family="paragraph" 
      style:parent-style-name="Table_20_Heading">
  <style:paragraph-properties fo:background-color="#c0c0c0">
    <style:background-image />
  </style:paragraph-properties>
</style:style>
```

Notice that background-color is inside style:paragraph-properties

Here's a background-color from content.xml:

```
<style:style style:name="Table1.C1" style:family="table-cell">
  <style:table-cell-properties 
       fo:background-color="#cccccc" 
       fo:padding="0.0382in" 
       fo:border="0.05pt solid #000000">
    <style:background-image />
  </style:table-cell-properties>
</style:style>
```

Here, background-color is within style:table-cell-properties

It seems that LibreOffice should have a 'Cell Styles' button in the `Styles and Formatting` dialog box (analogous to the 'Paragraph Styles' button).

Is this a bug?